# C++ Struct is compiled into class?

Tags: c++, struct, memory-layout

I am working on C++. I am using MVSV 2010.

When I compile a source code and dump the memory layout of all class with -d1reportAllClassLayout.

For example, I declare struct:

```
struct my_struct{
    int a;
};
```

And the memory layout of struct as following:

```
class my_struct size(4):
    +---
0   | a
    +---
```

Does it mean that C++ compiler consider struct as same as class at everything?
(Expept to default access specifier)

If that, then how about the constructor and deconstructor of struct?

Is there a default constructor and deconstructor of a struct? And it is similar to Class?

Thanks so much for your supports,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the notion of the class is defined the following way

```
class-specifier:
    class-head { member-specificationopt}
```

where class-head in turn is defined like

```
class-head:
    class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt class-head-name class-virt-specifieropt base-clauseopt
    class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt base-clauseopt
```

where

```
class-key:
    class
    struct
    union
```

Thus a structure is class  with class-key `struct`.

And (C++Standard 12.1 Constructors)

> 4 A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument. **If there is no user-declared
>   constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is
>   implicitly declared as defaulted** (8.4). An implicitly-declared
>   default constructor is an inline public member of its class...

As a structure is class and does not have a user-declared constructor then such a constructor is declared implicitly by the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ class and struct are (almost) exactly the same. The only difference between them is that the default of class is `private` and the default of struct is `public`

Comment: I know that as I discuss "Expept to default access specifier". But I would like to know about constructor, deconstructor of struct if struct is treated as same as class. I still not hear about it. Do you have knowledgement on it?

Comment: Constructors and destructor are exactly the same as in classes.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html)

> A well-designed class presents a clean and simple interface to its
>   users, hiding its representation and saving its users from having to
>   know about that representation. If the representation shouldn't be
>   hidden - say, because users should be able to change any data member
>   any way they like - you can think of that class as "**just a plain old
>   data structure**"; for example:

```
struct Pair {
   string name, value; };
```

A structure is a collection of similar or dissimilar data types. Classes extends the reach of structures by allowing the inclusion of functions within structures. Now, if a structure is just a collection of data-types, you can surely initialize them to some default value just like constructors or else the compiler will do it for you implicitly as mentioned in Vlad's answer but you would not be needing any destructors and there are no destructors by default.

Answer (score 0):

It could simply mean that d1reportAllClassLayout reports them both the same